# If a positive series converges, does its arithmetic mean sequence series converges

Tags: analysis

If a positive series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges,define the arithmetic mean $\sigma_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$, is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_n$ convergent. If it's not positive,the assertion is obviously wrong.And there is an analogous affirmative answer when exponent $p>1$, that is, Hardy inequality. So how to prove or disprove the assertion

I want to modify my word, it's not obvious when not positive (I made a low mistake before,) so what happens in this case

Comment: No, it fails for $a_n=\frac1{2^n}$ for example. Indeed, for positive series I think it *always* fails, since if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = A$ then $\sigma_n > \frac{A-\varepsilon}n$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original series is positive, $\sigma_n \ge \frac{a_1}{n}$ for all $n$. So the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_n$ diverges by  comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: To be precise, $a_1 > 0$ and for all $n$, $\sigma_n > \frac{a_1}{n}$. So $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \sigma_n$ diverges by comparison with $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n} = a_n \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: thank you all,I modified something